# SQL complicated differetnt type aggregation by rolling window

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, rdbms

I've stuck trying to create query for following task. Maybe someine can help me.

Input table:

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----------+-----------+
| Index  | Week_end_day | Type | Num_val_1 | Num_val_2 |
+--------+--------------+------+-----------+-----------+
| D0024A | 30.06.2018   | A    |        10 |         0 |
| D0024A | 30.06.2018   | A    |        20 |         0 |
| D0024A | 30.06.2018   | B    |        30 |         1 |
| A0025A | 30.06.2018   | C    |         5 |         1 |
| A0025A | 30.06.2018   | B    |         4 |         1 |
| A0025A | 30.06.2018   | B    |         6 |         0 |
| D0024A | 14.07.2018   | C    |         5 |         1 |
| D0024A | 14.07.2018   | A    |        10 |         1 |
+--------+--------------+------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to aggregate data by week, so that all numeric values will be summed, but at the same time aggregate some categorical values by another numerical column (average for example). Also need to count total rows per week and count each type per week.

Output table:

```
+--------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+---+---------------------+
| Index  | Week_Num | Type_A_avg_Num_val_1 | Type_B_avg_Num_val_1 | Type_C_avg_Num_val_1 | Sum_per_week - Num_val_1 | Sum_per_week - Num_val_2 | Type_A_count | . | total_count_in_week |
+--------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+---+---------------------+
| D0024A |        1 | 15                   | 30                   | 5                    | 60                       | 1                        | 2            | . | 6                   |
| D0024A |        2 | 10                   | 22                   | 10                   | 10                       | 2                        | 1            | . | 4                   |
| D0024A |        3 | 12                   | 14                   | 7                    | 50                       | 0                        | 3            | . | 5                   |
| D0025A |        1 | .                    | .                    | .                    | .                        | .                        | .            | . | .                   |
| D0025A |        2 | .                    | .                    | .                    | .                        | .                        | .            | . | .                   |
+--------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+---+---------------------+
```

I've got to this draft point:

```
SELECT
    Index,
    dense_rank() over(order by Week_end_date) AS Week_Num
    SUM(Num_val_1) AS SUM_Num_val_1,
    SUM(Num_val_2) AS SUM_Num_val_2,
    -- need average
    AVG(CASE WHEN Type = 'A' THEN Num_val_1 END) AS TypeA_avg_Num_val_1
    ....

    -- need to count
    SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS TypeA_count


FROM t1
GROUP BY Index, Week_end_date
```

Could you please have a look? I'm getting errors.

Also, dont know - is it important that Index and Week_end_day could be unsorted.

Comment: What error are you getting?  `index`, for instance, is a SQL keyword, so it is not a good choice for a column name.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon, I will fix it. Unfortunately now cant reproduce error, as tables are now reloading from source an temporary empty (need to wait couple hours).

Comment: Sorry, seems it was SQL mistakes, now everything is fine, thanks)
Do you know, is it important that Index and Week_end_day not sorted?

Comment: . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so your question doesn't really make sense.